# Google Sheets - List the Combinations of 2 Different Columns and Indicate How Many Times They Occur

Tags: list, google-sheets

Participants are paired together to accomplish a task.

I would like to have a list automatically made showing me how many times participants are paired with each other. This way, I get to pair the participants equally.

In the picture attached, you can see how I want the list generated at the far right. I was thinking "query" would work? But I'm not so familiar on how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have a look at the query documentation, particularly the Group By clause, you should be able to figure it out. If not, please let us know where you are having trouble. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example will show you the way:

1.Data are in A:B

2.Unique pair are in D:E - code: `=UNIQUE(A3:B)`

3.Number of times they where together are in F. Code for F3 and belowe:

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(A2:B6,"select B where A='"&D3&"' and B='"&E3&"'",0))
```

**Pictures:**
[image]
[image]

Is that what you where trying to get?

Comment: With the code you shared, I just had to use =SORT(UNIQUE( ) as the code doesn't automatically sort participant A. For COUNTA(QUERY(, I had to put $A$2:$B) to make sure the code is accurate. Thank you for sharing your solution! 

I have two questions.

(1) COUNTA doesn't automatically generate the data like QUERY. Is there another code to do that? 

(2) What if the range in UNIQUE is not adjacent? How would I modify the code?